# Google Maps: Polygon and Marker Z-Index

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map with many markers (yellow circles), and I implemented a tool to draw polygons over the markers. However, the polygon is behind the markers while drawing (and stays behind when complete).

[image: Active polygon drawing tool beneath the markers.]

I tried changing the ZIndex in both markers and polygons, but it seems to alter the way in which markers are shown with respect to other markers, and not with respect to polygons. I also tried

```
polygon.setZIndex(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);
```

How can I bring the polygon to the front?

Comment: You may be able to use [Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays). I have no experience with Google's API, but I could show you how to do it in Bing Maps.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This won't solve the problem, but it will explain why the things you tried didn't work.

The Maps API uses several layers known as [MapPanes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes) in a fixed Z order:

- 4: floatPane (infowindow)
- 3: overlayMouseTarget (mouse events)
- 2: markerLayer (marker images)
- 1: overlayLayer (polygons, polylines, ground overlays, tile layer overlays)
- 0: mapPane (lowest pane above the map tiles)

So the marker images in layer 2 are always above the polygons in layer 1. When you fiddle with the z-index on the markers, you're just adjusting them relative to each other. That doesn't do any good, because they are all in a layer above the polygons.

What can you do about this? The only solution I can think of is to create your own [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView) for the polygons or the markers so you can put them in the MapPane you want.

Are your markers clickable, or are they just static images? If they aren't clickable, you could possibly get away with drawing them yourself in the `mapPane`. Then your polygons would be above them. Or the opposite: you could draw the polygons yourself in one of the higher layers, maybe in `floatShadow`.

The problem then is you have to do all of your own drawing, either with a `canvas` element or with DOM images. And your own mouse hit testing too if they are clickable.

There aren't a lot of good `OverlayView` examples out there, but I'll mention one of my own: a little library I wrote a while ago called [PolyGonzo](https://github.com/geary/polygonzo), where the [polygonzo.js](https://github.com/geary/polygonzo/blob/master/code/polygonzo.js) file has the `OverlayView` implementation. The code isn't great - I threw it together in too much of a hurry - but it may help give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The markers are clickable, and the polygons are drawn by the users and that is why I wanted to go with the google.maps.drawing library.

Comment: Bummer. Yeah, the way they put polygons in the `overlayLayer` makes it tricky. You either have to implement your own polygons or your own markers. No easy solution here. You could implement your own markers and put them way down in the `mapLayer`, with matching transparent elements in the `overlayMouseTarget` layer for mouse hit testing.

Comment: Partially transparent markers might be a possible compromise, allowing the underlying polygon to be seen under the markers. Not perfect, but simple with custom .png image(s).

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thank you very much!! Saved my time

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is old but for future users I wanna share my approach:

Shapes with higher `zIndex` values displaying in front of those with lower values. For this example I am using Polygon but is similar for other shapes:

```
var globalZIndex = 1; //Be sure you can access anywhere
//... Other instructions for creating map, polygon and any else
polygon.setOptions({ zIndex: globalZIndex++ });
```

Notice that markers have a method `setZIndex(zIndex:number)`.

Comment: FIX: setZIndex(number)

Comment: This does not work. Markers are always above polygons and polylines

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question.

Answer (score -2):

I found this solution

To Create a **Symbol** use this code below

```
var lineSymbol = {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                strokeColor: '#181727',
                fillColor: '#50040B', 

            };

            var dashedSymbol = {
                path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                scale: 4

            };

 [![function  MakeMarker(pinColor){
                var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
                        new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                        new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

                return pinImage;

            }][1]][1]

FlowMarkersdashed(new google.maps.LatLng(positionorigin[0], positionorigin[1]),
                                new google.maps.LatLng(positiondestination[0], positiondestination[1]), myObject[i]['flowfluxphysique'][j]['colorFlux'], dashedSymbol, j);

            function FlowMarkersdashed(latlngOrgin, latlngDest, ColorFlow, Symbol,  indexvar){

                var flightPlanCoordinates = [
                    latlngOrgin,
                    {lat: latlngOrgin.lat() + (indexvar) * 2, lng: latlngOrgin.lng()},
//                    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
                    latlngDest,
                ];
                var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                    strokeOpacity: 0,
                    icons: [{
                        icon: Symbol,
//                        offset: '100%',
                        offset: '0',
                        repeat: '20px'

//                    repeat: '20px'
                    }],
                    strokeColor: "#"+ColorFlow,
                    geodesic: true,

//                    editable: true,

                    map: map
                });
            }
```

And to Create a **Flow Marker** try this code

```
FlowMarkers(new google.maps.LatLng(positionorigin[0], positionorigin[1]),
                               new google.maps.LatLng(positiondestination[0], positiondestination[1]), myObject[i]['flowfluxinformation'][j]['colorFlux'], lineSymbol,j);


function FlowMarkersdashed(latlngOrgin, latlngDest, ColorFlow, Symbol,  indexvar){

                var flightPlanCoordinates = [
                    latlngOrgin,
                    {lat: latlngOrgin.lat() + (indexvar) * 2, lng: latlngOrgin.lng()},
//                    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
                    latlngDest,
                ];
                var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                    strokeOpacity: 0,
                    icons: [{
                        icon: Symbol,
//                        offset: '100%',
                        offset: '0',
                        repeat: '20px'

//                    repeat: '20px'
                    }],
                    strokeColor: "#"+ColorFlow,
                    geodesic: true,

//                    editable: true,

                    map: map
                });
            }
```

This is my result

[image]

Comment: How does this provide any kind of solution to the original question?

Answer (score -3):

Change this method call:

```
polygon.setZIndex(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);
```

to this:

```
polygon.setZIndex(4);
```