# Google maps polyline click between two narrow markers is wrong

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I have two narrow markers connected by a polyline. When I try to click on the polyline the method `OnPolylineClickListener` is never called because the event is intercepted by `OnMarkerClickListener` of the nearest marker.

When the distance between the two markers is greater the correct method is called.

There is a way to prioritize the click on the polyline?

[The two markers connected by a polyline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvkG6.jpg)

Comment: See a good explanation of the layers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627325/google-maps-polygon-and-marker-z-index.  Basically poly* are in a separate layer "beneath" the marker layer.

Comment: There are coding solutions though; for example, implementing your marker listener to check if the marker point is on a polyline (using the android-maps-utils 'isLocationOnPath') - so therefore you manage a collection of polylines and for every marker click check if the point is on a polyline - if so then invoke the polyline listener logic.

Comment: @Andy this is a good solution but can it be impletemented on android? I didn't find documentation about mapPane.

Comment: @Andy I know there is "maps utils", but I also need to listen to marker click. In fact my temporary solution will be implementing a toggle for switching click mode so that I can check with "isLocationOnPath" on the marker.

Comment: Sounds like your issue is related to bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823783